# Java annotations for design patterns?

Tags: java, design-patterns, annotations

Is there a project that maintains annotations for patterns?

For example, when I write a builder, I want to mark it with `@Builder`.

Annotating in this way immediately provides a clear idea of what the code implements. Also, the Javadoc of the `@Builder` annotation can reference explanations of the builder pattern. Furthermore, navigating from the Javadoc of a builder implementation to `@Builder` Javadoc is made easy by annotating `@Builder` with `@Documented`.

I've being slowing accumulating a small set of such annotations for patterns and idioms that I have in my code, but I'd like to leverage a more complete existing project if it exists. If there is no such project, maybe I can share what I have by spinning it off to a separate pattern/idiom annotation project.

Update: I've created the [Pattern Notes project](http://code.google.com/p/patternnotes) in response to this discussion. Contributions welcome! Here is [`@Builder`](http://code.google.com/p/patternnotes/source/browse/trunk/trunk/src/com/iparelan/annotations/patterns/Builder.java)

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question but I'm wondering why you want to do this?  Unless it's some really obscure design pattern, I think most developers will be able to spot them without any extra documentation.

Couldn't you just name your class WhateverBuilder?

Comment: I see your point, but there are developers of all skill levels, so general assumptions can be dangerous. It doesn't consume much space or time to add the annotations. Also, linking to supporting docs reduces the need to repeat docs in place with a convenient centralized point to collect docs.

Comment: I can see the benefit of having documentation produced automatically that would identify the role of each class used in a pattern. Sometime's it's not completely obvious.

Comment: I just don't see the value in labeling something as "this follows pattern X."  I mean, what does it get you?  Are you trying to keep other developers from modifying your code and breaking the pattern?

Comment: Continuing with @Builder as an example. The Javadoc for my @Builder references "Effective Java" Item 2 which is a well-written, 6-page discussion of the pattern by an expert. I'd like that to be in the mind of a developer when maintaining the code. It's about consistency, not "don't touch this."

Comment: A big reason this is useful is to help document your intent.

When someone else is looking at some code of yours, having an annotation or comment saying "Builder", for example, helps them understand why you wrote the code the way you did.

Comment: What if somebody has a different idea of what a Builder is than what Josh Bloch says in Effective Java?  That is far from the only way to write a builder, and other methods are just as "correct".

Comment: That's a great point. My linked code actually has a reference to the Gang of Four's material on builder as well. Now, that might not be  indisputably "correct" either. But, it doesn't matter. The annotation doc links to reasonable references that can give background to those who need or want it.

Comment: Ahhh... the trick is not to think of a design pattern as "an implementation", but as "an intent".

There are many way to implement any of the patterns. But the intent remains the same. I think too many books and articles concentrate on implementations.

Comment: I like your approach, but I doubt if it's ok to use annotations because an annotation is linked to a class (the thing) and not to the configuration it's in (the design pattern). By example: I can make a filter class (ProcessorImpl<A,B>) that does some interesting thing. It's strategy pattern because it implements polymorphically an interface and configure ProducerA -> ProcessorImpl<A,B> -> Processor<B,?>... but where do I put @Strategy? **It's its use -not the thing- that makes the pattern.**

Answer (score 8):

This seems like a misuse of annotations to me. Sure, I could see why you might want to note what design pattern a class is helping to implement, but just using the Javadoc and/or the name of the class seems more appropriate. The name of the pattern that you're using is of no actual importance to the code itself... patterns are just a guide for an often used way of solving a problem. A comment would suffice, rather than creating a new file for every pattern you use.

Comment: Good point, but my scheme does have a comment: it's the Javadoc of the annotation. That's why the annotation is @Documented. The annotation links to docs that might otherwise be duplicated

Comment: I agree with @ColinD, I see no value in knowing what pattern a piece of code says it is using, as a comment or annotation.

Comment: Intent! Adding a comment or annotation to state which patterns are being used helps communicate the design intent to the reader/maintainer. This can help them decide where to make changes that might be needed later.

Comment: @ScottStanchfield there are better ways to communicate intent. If the pattern is already being used, class names or (in rare cases when they aren't indicative) comments in key areas would suffice. If a pattern isn't being used yet, it's a call for a comment like "refactor this to Strategy pattern if the switch grows too large". Unlike annotations, comments aren't constrained in form or place.

Comment: Besides, annotations are designed to be machine-readable at runtime. There's no reason to check the patterns used at runtime.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Annotations don't _have_ to be readable at runtime. They aren't unless they're marked `@Retention(RUNTIME)`.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev By marking an annotation RUNTIME, it's available to any reflection code that runs against the class. This may be useful if you want to write an instrumentation framework that reports patterns used at runtime, for example. Otherwise, I'd still recommend they at least be CLASS so tools that examine the jars can see them.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev Naming conventions and comments are incredibly unreliable - you can misspell them. Annotations were created for compile-time checking of metadata (which was a problem with many javadoc-based metadata - if you misspell it, it's ignored). By using an annotation to indicate your pattern usage, you can't misspell it or you get a compiler error.

Answer (score 6):

This is an interesting solution, but I keep wondering what's really the problem you're solving with this? Or in other words, what do you get from using something like this what you don't get by a proper comment on top of your class about it's usage?

I can think of a few cons but can't think of benefits apart from this being the nice standardized way to document code.

Cons would be, namely:

1. one more thing for programmers to think about, which is never a good thing
2. unannotated patterns might be confusing - someone probably forgot to document it, but maybe it's not a pattern..?
3. can you really annotate all patterns..? what about patterns which are not tied to a single class/method, for example three-tier architectural pattern, or thread pool, or even MVC?

Comment: (Problem solved/more to think about): I'd bet most of us have opened a source file and quickly asked, "What were the previous developers thinking when they wrote this?" This idea of applying pattern annotations helps to answer such questions. Answering questions like that, even if only partially, provides a valuable "big picture" view for a section of code. Also, with @Documented links, more background material can be found easily. The burden for this additional pattern information is small.

Comment: (Applicability/Coverage): It probably doesn't matter whether all patterns /can/ be annotated, or whether all patterns /are/ annotated in practice. Every little bit helps to increase value. Today, we have lots of code that isn't explicitly marked with intended patterns. The absence of an annotation doesn't mean that some pattern isn't there, just that it isn't documented.

Comment: (Patterns spread across various locations): The notion of patterns that are spread across different sections of code is interesting. Just yesterday I applied the Template View pattern (http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/templateView.html) which has a "Template" and a "Helper." Annotating the Helper with @TemplateView seemed to tell only part of the story. Perhaps the notion of a "role" should be introduced. For example, @TemplateView(role = "Helper"), or @MVC(role = "Model").

Answer (score 5):

Michael Hunger and I have started an open-source project for annotations to specify what patterns the classes belong to.  We are right at the beginning stages, but would love to hear your input.

I would like to go with the KISS principle in order to make it as easy as possible for people to use the annotations.  For example, if you are writing an adapter, you can simply say:

```
@AdapterPattern
public class EnumerationIteratorAdapter<T> implements Enumeration<T> {
  ...
}
```

Of course, you can specify more information if you want, for example the role, the participants and a comment.  We hope that this will make it easy for developers to mark-up their classes clearly.

The project home is on http://www.jpatterns.org from where you can also access the initial source tree.  Please contact me on heinz at javaspecialists dot eu if you would like to contribute to the project.

Heinz (The Java Specialists' Newsletter)

Answer (score 4):

I just stumbled on another article that is interesting for you: [Design Markers - Explicit Programming for the Rest of Us](http://onjava.com/lpt/a/3340) which talks about marker interfaces, like `Serializable`.

In their words:

> ...just because a class declares that it "implements Serializable" doesn't mean that it has correctly implemented the Serializable contract.
>
> Since Java can't really tell if the contract has been met, using the marker interface is more of an explicit pledge by the programmer that it has.
>
> The overlooked benefit of marker interfaces is that they also document the intention that a contract should be met...

> Why haven't design choices traditionally been recorded in source code? Mostly, because there has been no clear place to put them.
>
> Even if each "typesafe enumeration" class had a comment noting that it followed that pattern, any elaboration (much less tutorial information) would not have been added because one either had to copy it repeatedly, or worse, place it sporadically in arbitrary spots.
>
> When creating the JavaDoc comments attached to each Design Marker interface, one can put in more detail than is typical because the comments do not need to be repeated anywhere else.

They also mention some downsides, this a good food for thought!

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, what you want to do is documenting an intention (or intention*s*).

So, why not use a generic version of your annotation, something like **@UsePattern** that use [@Documented](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Documented.html) which is a marker annotation ([nice tuorial from IBM](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-annotate2.html#N101FE))? What i don't like is that the annotation is kept at runtime, which is a waste unless you want to affect program semantics.

Or a [Custom Javadoc tag](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/javadoc.html#tag) which seems more appropriate.

Some information about the comparison: [Comparing Annotations and Javadoc Tags](http://java.sun.com/j2se/javadoc/writingdoccomments/index.html#annotations) with a nice one sentence summmary:

<< **In general, if the markup is intended to affect or produce documentation, it should probably be a javadoc tag; otherwise, it should be an annotation.** >>

There is/was also some debate on [documentation as annotation or as javadoc tags](http://forums.java.net/jive/thread.jspa?threadID=247).

Comment: These are great points and great resource links - thanks! The majority of my annotations do have a Source retention policy, so they are not kept at runtime. As for custom Javadoc tags: how would I share them? Annotations can be packaged up as a jar, but custom Javadoc tags are implemented with command line switches - not as easy to share. Also, annotations open the possiblity of creating tools that can check pattern implementation consistency. The comparison of annotations and Javadoc tags says that annotations "affect the way programs are treated by tools and libraries."

Answer (score 3):

What would be better would be to use annotations to actually build the boilerplate for a Builder.  Let's face it most are pretty standard.

```
@Builder("buildMethodName")
Class Thing {
  String thingName;
  String thingDescr;
}
```

Typical useage:

```
Thing thing =
      new Thing.Builder().setThingName("X").setThingDescr("x").buildMethodName();
```

Answer (score 1):

Else there is this 2008 Computer Science paper: [Design Pattern Implementation in Java and AspectJ](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/labs/spl/papers/2002/oopsla02-patterns.pdf), it was presented at OOPSLA 2008, which should give an indication about its quality.

A nice quote from it:

> ... the mere existence of classes that exclusively contain pattern code serve as records of what patterns are being used. In the AspectJ cases, we observe two additional improvements. First, all code related to a particular pattern instance is contained in a single module (which defines participants, assigns roles, etc.). This means that the entire description of a pattern instance is localized and does not “get lost” [21] or “degenerate” [7] in the system. Secondly, with the current AspectJ IDE support, all references, advised methods etc. are hyperlinks that allow a developer an overview of the assignment of roles and where the conceptual operations of interest are...

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a misuse of annotations to me. Unless there is the intention of implementing behavior with those annotations, I'd use the KISS principle: Plain ol' javadoc does fine for documenting what the artifact is supposed to do/be; custom doclets for extending javadoc; and google for those who want to know what a X or Y pattern is for (or a link to it somewhere on the web.)

There are excellent, quasi-official explanations for most patterns out there. Why writing your own? Is there additional information that is crucial for the project? Using annotations to make sure one can navigate from one class' javadoc to a custom-written pattern javadoc is like the tale of the CEO who assembled a development team for creating a report that combines the totals of two existing quarterly reports - it was too difficult (and yet cheaper) to add the totals of the two with a calculator 4 times a year :-/

Answer (score 0):

If you can also write an annotation processor that will verify certain properties of the pattern - for example checking for common mistakes when implementing the pattern - this would be very useful.  Documentation for the compiler as well as the programmer.

Comment: Yes, I've had this though as well. I seems like a reasonable next step to investigate. Though it's not immediately clear what properties could be verified since there is no one way to implement any particular pattern. Such a solution would likely produce a certain number of "false positives" like other QA tools. That doesn't mean that such a tool would be without value. With enough metadata, perhaps false positives could be kept reasonably low.

Comment: @GregMattes One thing that is hard to verify in this way is assumptions: e.g., in Observer we assume that Subjects don't want to know directly their Observers; in Visitor, we assume the Element hierarchy is fixed and that we want to add new functionality via ConcreteVisitors; in Façade, the methods provided are a simplification of the underlying subsystem and have multiple Clients, etc. I think an effective way to document patterns should capture these assumptions (for perhaps human verification). If/When they are no longer valid, a pattern is superfluous. How many developers remove patterns?

Answer (score -2):

First off all this is a very good idea and I'm only hanging out here because I googled for a "design pattern annotation" library. Good I found this! I will check it out and give feed back on it soon.

To all the skeptics: sorry obviously most of you are not very experienced in the topic of design patters. E.g. Martin Harris's post from Dec 3 '09 at 21:56 ... 
I understand you wanted to keep your "example" simple. But that is not a Builder in the sense of the Design Pattern.

The same I want to say to those who don't see the usefulness at all. If the relations of classes regarding to their roles in design patters are annotated to the class, I can use a generator to craft the boilerplate code. I see all relations on top of the class in the source code and can use my IDE shortcuts to navigate to the relevant classes.

If you have learned to think in patterns and all patterns are obvious in the source code (via comments or annotations) you can grasp a system composed of 200 classes in less than an hour.

Regarding suggestions like using @UsePattern() or @Builder("buildMethodName")
 etc. ... here we have to ask, how to make it "typesave"? After all those strings are prone to typos.

One advantage of proper annotations is that you can annotate roles ... Most Design Patterns do not consist out of a single class (like Singleton) but out of several classes working together! E.g. if you have a builder the result (annotated with @Product) might be also a @Composite. So the parts the builder is putting together will be @Component (in regard to the @Composite) and a @Part (in regard to the @Builder and the @Product).

Perhaps the best argument to such annotations would be java.lang.class, so you can express that.

Anyway, just a few thoughts ... I cant await to get home and play with the stuff you have so far ^^

Comment: While these related thoughts may contribute to the discussion, this doesn't seem to be an answer to the question proper.